# How to communicate between two applications?

Tags: wcf

I have created a library which reads the app.config file and gets the type of WCF service in which it is called.

Now, I have a separate console application,  I want that this library informs the console application about the type it found in the WCF service so that the console application can host it.

It is useful because then I will just add my library in any WCF service and call its method and it will then inform my console application and it will host it.

Please give me an idea on this problem.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to accomplish here? I don't seem to fully understand what you're trying to do....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to agree with Marc, but this is perhaps related to your question regarding ServiceHost, but what is the purpose of your console application?

Is it acting as a host or as client (consumer of the services).  If its a host I would simply add the appropraite configuration in the app.config?

HTH

Phil'